# JS Regex lookbehind feature alternative (not working in Safari browser)

Tags: regex, safari, lookbehind

I'm having an issue with running my webpage with Safari (Safari does not support RegEx lookbehind feature).
The code is following:

```
const str1 = "[]{}<>,^!";
const str2 = "\[\]{\}\<\>\,\^\!";

str1.split(/(?<!\\),/); => expected output: ["[]{}<>", "^!"];

str2.split(/(?<!\\),/); => expected output: ["\[\]{\}\<\>\,\^\!"]
```

Is there an alternative way to implement the code above for Safari?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use `const str2 = "\\[\\]{\\}\\<\\>\\,\\^\\!";` to define a `\[\]{\}\<\>\,\^\!` string.

Then you need

```js
text.match(/(?:\\[^]|[^\\,])+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/17Zgo3/1). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\\[^]` - a `\` char and then any single char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\\,]` - any one char other than a `\` and `,`
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times.